# Bottom InfoWIndow with Flutter Google Maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, maps, display

I want to make something like Google Maps app. When I click a specific pin on the map, it will display a bottom window with general info about the place, as well the option to expand up the info page.

Is something like the images:

[image]

[image]

In the first one, I've clicked in Light Frei Caneca Pin, and a bottom info window has been displayed. In the second, I slipped it up and a window with all possible information has been shown.

How do I do this bottom info window? I don't even no how to start, but I'm assuming that it's gonna be something like:

```
Marker m = new Marker(
      markerId: new MarkerId(myPin.id),
      position: myPin.position,
      infoWindow: myCustomInfoWindow(myPin));

mapMarkers.add(m);
```

Comment: I'd start with a Stack.  Have the map take the whole screen, and when a marker is selected slide up a widget that host the details for the selected location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did a lot of research about how to do a "slide up widget", and I've found this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel).

It works very well, and saved me a lot of time.